# Continous update variable value based on previous value

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying a update value of the sales column based on previously updated value. for example -

Table A

```
Day    growth sales
1       1.1   1
2       1.2   NULL
3       1.3   NULL
```

I want to update the sales value based on growth. 
So, for day 2 it would be day1 sales * growth. 
and day 3 would be day 2 updated sales * growth. 
Is this possible without a loop in netezza ? 
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum and logs to get a cumulative product:

```
select t.*,
       (case when day = 1 then sales
             else (exp(sum(ln(growth)) over (order by day) / growth) *
                  max(case when day = 1 then sales end) over ()
        end) as new_sales
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @_i NUMERIC(18,2)  = (SELECT Sales FROM A WHERE Day = '1')

UPDATE A
SET @_i = Sales = @_i * CASE WHEN _Day = '1' THEN (SELECT Sales FROM A WHERE Day = '1') 
ELSE  GROWTH END

SELECT * FROM A
```

Here is my answer, try this